Can I travel back to Ireland with old Irish Resident Permit Card which hasn’t expired
I am an Indian passport holder with Irish residency currently travelling internationally with my Irish Resident Permit (IRP) card which expires on the 24th of January, 2025.
Just before I left Ireland, I had applied to renew my IRP which was approved and the card was sent in the post to my address in Ireland.
Will I have any issues when trying to re-enter Ireland with my old IRP card which is still in date since I don’t have access to my new one?
